# How include css in html with jersey / grizzly

Tags: java, html, css, maven, grizzly

This is what my project look like :

```
src/main/java
-- main.java
src/main/resources
-- webapp
-- -- css
-- -- js
-- -- images
-- -- pages
-- -- -- home.html
```

Actually my maven project works with jersey and grizzly. I can call my services (Rest) and call html static pages (clstatichttphandler). The problem is when then file "home.html" is loaded, there is no css or images. I tried to set the path to the css relatively from the "home.html" file but it's not working.

I think my css / images are not visible.

EDIT

Here is the file which start the server grizzly - Main.java

```
    public static HttpServer startServer() {
    // create a resource config that scans for JAX-RS resources and providers
    // in com.application.easyshow package
    final ResourceConfig rc = new ResourceConfig().packages("com.application.app", "com.businessLogic");
    // create and start a new instance of grizzly http server
    // exposing the Jersey application at BASE_URI
    HttpServer server = GrizzlyHttpServerFactory.createHttpServer(URI.create(BASE_URI), rc);

    server.getServerConfiguration().addHttpHandler(
            new org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.CLStaticHttpHandler(Main.class.getClassLoader(), "/webapp/pages/"), "/app");

    return server;
}
```

And this is the `<head>` where I try to load my css and js - home.html

```
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Soundbyte Template</title>
<meta name="description" content="">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/style.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/responsive.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../Player/css/progression-player.css" />
<link href="../Player/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href='//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins:400,600,700%7cRoboto:400,300,700,900' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>    
<script src="../js/libs/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script> 
<script src="../js/libs/jquery-migrate.min.js"></script>
<script src="../js/libs/modernizr-2.6.2.min.js"></script>
</head>
```

What my project looks like

[image: My Project]

Comment: Could you please provide us more informations ? Code ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem can be that the path of the css files is not proper. If you write directly css/images. It starts from the **base directory of HTML**, you can either put your css/folder there. Or start from say, project_name/main/resources/css/images.

Hope it helps. :)

Comment: @Skulker Try putting css folder in the directory where html is kept and in href, change to ./ 
instead of ../ . It should work fine

Comment: thank you, my website is beautiful now ^^. I don't know why it can't go back for 1 level but i'm glad that I can keep going with this.

Comment: If you found your answer, then you mark it as answered. :)